# Referencing a file in Eclipse without hard-coding the path?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I'm creating a dynamic web project in Eclipse where I frequently have write and read to and from an XML file. The file is in my project workspace in a folder called xml. I was wondering if Java provided some way to access the file without hard coding the file path. I've been looking around for a while for a solution but I haven't really founding anything that's really clear. Thanks!

Comment: `getResource()`/`getResourceAsStream()` are probably what you want...

Comment: @Oli: for read, yes, but to write? No.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, yes, I hadn't spotted the write requirement... (It's a good thing I didn't put this in an answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the proper path using the following from your Servlet:

```
String filename = getServletContext().getRealPath("/xml/config.xml");
```

NOTE:

`getRealPath` may return `null` if the file is inside a WAR file. In that case, if your file is in `WEB_INF/classes`, then you could use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/config.xml")`.

See this [link](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=5272):

Comment: If you go this path with `getRealPath()` (which will by the way be `null` when the WAR is expanded in memory instead of in disk, not just when you have a WAR), all changes will be lost whenever you redeploy the WAR or even when you restart the server, simply because those changes are not contained in the original WAR.

Answer (score 2):

You could just drop it in the classpath as suggested by others, but you won't be able to write to it.

Rather supply the absolute path as a VM argument or environment variable so that you don't need to hardcode it.

E.g.

```
-Dconfig.location=/path/to/config/file
```

with

```
File xmlFile = new File(System.getProperty("config.location"), "some.xml");
// ...
```

As a completely different alternative, you could consider a database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Servlet API gives you anything that would result in a reliable, writable, path to put work files in all containers.  If your container runs the WebApp right out of the WAR, getRealPath() couldn't possibly point to something you can actually write to.  I think that your only option here that is supported regardless of container is to hard code some path in the web.xml.  Do it as a Context Parameter and you may be able to change it at deployment time.  At the end of the day, you must declare a fully qualified path in either code or configuration to get the effect you seek.

Alternatively, do you really need to know the name of the file?  In some Servlet apps I've managed to get the effect of dynamically writable storage through plain-jane java.io.file.createTempFile:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)